# Configuring near cache with Hazelcast

Tags: caching, local, hazelcast

good day everyone

Im trying to use Hazelcast as a local cache in SpringBoot app, following tutorial:
https://hazelcast.com/blog/non-stop-client-with-near-cache/

Hazelcast gradle version:

```
com.hazelcast:hazelcast-client:3.12.11 -> 3.12.10 \
```

In my version I see no method to set up max timeout for connection to cluster
(setClusterConnectTimeoutMillis()):

```
HazelcastInstance member = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.getConnectionStrategyConfig().setReconnectMode(ClientConnectionStrategyConfig.ReconnectMode.ASYNC);
config.getConnectionStrategyConfig().getConnectionRetryConfig().setClusterConnectTimeoutMillis(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

NearCacheConfig nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfig("map");
config.addNearCacheConfig(nearCacheConfig);

HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
```

.. and withought it it falls with

> com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientOfflineException: Client
> connecting to cluster

Any alternative to set up it by java config in my Hazelcast version ?

Comment: hi tarmogoyf , that blog post contains Hazelcast  version 4.x and `setClusterConnectTimeoutMillis ` method is not placed under 3.12.x version.  Can you update the hazelcast version and try again? If any similar issue occurs, you can share the whole exception stacktrace.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, cause Im bind to company's repo.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives to client near-cache setup is using declarative in hazelcast-client.xml or yaml files. Near Cache can also be configured for members using their xml or yaml file.

See...
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/clients/client-near-cache/src/main/resources/hazelcast-client.xml

Also docs...
https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/performance/near-cache.html#near-cache-example-for-imap